# For with method invocation on Java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How can I write the following using `Stream`s?

```
List<CardInfoRow> result = resp.fetchCards();
for(CardInfoRow row: result) {
    responceEnvelope.getCardInfo().add(row.convertRowToModel());
}
```

I tried

```
result.stream.peek(el ->el.getCardInfo()).foreach(CardInfoRow::convertRowToModel)
```

but it's not working.

Comment: what is responceEnvelope?

Comment: responceEnvelope -it is custom object

Answer (score 2):

First you can `map` each `CardInfoRow` to its corresponding model, and then you can use `forEach` to add the models to `responceEnvelope.getCardInfo()`.

```
result.stream()
      .map(CardInfoRow::convertRowToModel)
      .foreach(model -> responceEnvelope.getCardInfo().add(model));
```